# How to list the Connected USB Port Number using Vendor id and product id using java

Tags: java, usb

What is the best API in java to display the connected USB port number using Vendor id and product id?

Comment: `using Vendor id and product id` .. Sorry?

Comment: Normally every usb devices has vendor id and unique product id. By using that we can able to open the device and start read and write operations. @freak

Comment: You need to do it on windows or linux? Try [java libusb](http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net/wp/)

Comment: Ya i already tried LibusbJava to display the connected USB port number but i cannot able to get it.Using jsr 80 i get the connected usb hub number but not the usb port number.@freak

Comment: Iam using Windows @freak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all serial ports by using simple `javax.comm` API

```
import javax.comm.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class ListPorts {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier)ports.nextElement();
String type;
switch (port.getPortType()) {
case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
type = "Serial"; 
break;
default: /// Shouldn't happen
type = "Unknown"; 
break;
}
System.out.println(port.getName() + ": " + type);
}
}
}
```

The output would be like

```
COM1: Serial
COM2: Serial
COM7: Serial
```

**EDIT**:
Also see a good blog on [Creating and using a real-time port monitoring application powered by IBM Lotus](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/sametime-healthcheck/).
Also by using jusb [for windows](http://www.steelbrothers.ch/jusb/) , [for linux](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) you can do read and write operation which you want.you will find a [a example here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just found an good sulotion to get all ports names in java using [JserialComm.jar](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) library

```
private void getports() {
    ArrayList dataarr = new ArrayList();
    SerialPort[] ar = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ar.length) {
        String PortCom = ar[i].getDescriptivePortName();

        dataarr.add(PortCom);
        ++i;
    }
}
```